# Set tab text color using pagerslidingtablayout

Tags: java, android, pagerslidingtabstrip

I am trying to implement tablayout using pagerslidingtabStrip. I want to set the color of the selected tabs and unselected tabs. And there is an attribute that have been recently added to the library "pstsactivateTextColor" but it gets an error while building:

> No resource identifier found for attribute 'pstsTabTextColor'

I use the "astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip" library.

Comment: What error do you get? What language and operating system? Is this an Android question?

Comment: yeah this is an android question. trying to build an android application which has a tab layout and i use the "astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip" library...Error is "No resource identifier found for attribute 'pstsTabTextColor' .. want to change tab text color for both selected and unselected tabs

Answer (score 0):

Acording to this [article](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/issues/178), you could set the color of the selected tabs and unselected tabs if you add attr by yourself:

```
<attr name="pstsTabSelectedTextColor" format="color" />
<attr name="pstsTabUnselectedTextColor" format="color" />
```

in the "PagerSlidingTabStrip" file, add those:

```
private static final int DEFAULT_TAB_TEXT_COLOR = 0xFF666666;
private  int tabSelectedTextColor;
private  int tabUnselectedTextColor;
```

remove the "tabTextColor" field and anything that is related to it.
in the CTOR, add this:

```
tabSelectedTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabSelectedTextColor, DEFAULT_TAB_TEXT_COLOR);
    tabUnselectedTextColor = a.getColor(R.styleable.PagerSlidingTabStrip_pstsTabUnselectedTextColor, DEFAULT_TAB_TEXT_COLOR);
```

in the code, add setters&getters for the new fields I've written. Add this method:

```
private void updateTabsTextColors() {
    for (int i = 0; i < tabCount; i++) {
        View v = tabsContainer.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tab = (TextView) v;
            if (pager.getCurrentItem() == i)
                tab.setTextColor(tabSelectedTextColor);
            else tab.setTextColor(tabUnselectedTextColor);
        }
    }
}
```

call this function inside "onPageSelected" of the "PageListener" class, in the new setters, and in the end of "updateTabStyles" .